# Cannot transfer tez

Tags: blockchain

I am using the node: https://babylonnet.tezos.org.ua

I am using taquito node module to test a faucet account:

```
taquito.Tezos.setProvider({rpc:'https://babylonnet.tezos.org.ua'})
taquito.Tezos.importKey(email,password,mnemonic.join(" "),secret)
taquito.Tezos.contract.transfer({to:address,amount:amount})  
.then(op=>{console.log(op.confirmation)})
.then(block=>{console.log(block)})
.catch(error=>{console.log(JSON.stringify(error))})
```

The output is:

```
{
  "message": "Http error response: (400) Failed to parsed an argument in    path. After \"chains/main/blocks/head/context/contracts/balance\", the value \"Cannot parse contract id\" is not acceptable for type \"contract_id\"",
  "status": 400,
  "statusText": "Bad Request",
  "body": "Failed to parsed an argument in path. After \"chains/main/blocks/head/context/contracts/balance\", the value \"Cannot parse contract id\" is not acceptable for type \"contract_id\"",
  "name": "HttpResponse"
}
```

How do i successfully send tez?

Comment: read this may you can find some help
https://medium.com/@jiki99887651/tutorial-how-to-resolve-tezbox-wallet-error-operation-failed-9c4a2e40f57f

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your code because you are not sending an address to the RPC-URL. The error says this:

`Failed to parsed an argument in path. After "chains/main/blocks/head/context/contracts/balance"`

But the correct path should be this, as example:

`chains/main/blocks/head/context/contracts/tz1YH2LE6p7Sj16vF6irfHX92QV45XAZYHnX/balance`

So you are missing a key piece of information when fetching the balance, which is the address itself. Check the variable 'address' and make sure it is populated.

Comment: Yes it has an address:

Comment: const address='tz....'
    const amount=2
    taquito.Tezos.importKey(email,password,mnemonic.join(' '),secret)
    taquito.Tezos.contract.transfer({to: address,amount: amount})
    .then(op=>{console.log(op.confirmation)}) 
    .then(block=>{console.log(block)})
    .catch(error=>{console.log(JSON.stringify(error))})

Comment: The variable address is a "const address='tz.....'"

Comment: Well, again, for whatever reason, the code you have is not putting the address into the URL for the RPC call. I don't use Taquito; I can only tell you that what it is doing is not correct. The address has to be part of the "/balance" URL call.